# How to find bot owner

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command where you can say (prefix)owner <@bot>
[According to discord.py Docs about AppInfo,](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AppInfo) if i got it correctly, i must user `discord.AppInfo` and `.owner` to find the bot owner. But i get error `discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "AppInfo" failed.`! I'm not sure where I've gone wrong

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def owner(ctx,app:discord.AppInfo):
    if app.bot==True:
        try:
            await client.say(f"Bot owner is: {app.owner}")
        except Exception as e:
            await client.say(e)
    else:
        await client.say("Not a bot")
```

Comment: You can only get your own `AppInfo` object, through the [`Client.application_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.application_info) coroutine.

Comment: I used `app:discord.Client.application_info):` but still get error saying `Converting to "application_info" failed.`

Comment: Are you trying to get the info for your bot? Just do `info = await client.application_info()`. I don't think you can get that information about other bots.

Comment: I'm trying to get info for other bots, but no problem if it isn't possible. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to get that "private" information about other bots.